# Delete Node - Linked List - C

Tags: c, linked-list, global-variables

I am trying to delete a node from a linked list but I am still new to the concept of double pointers so I tried using a global variable to hold the head pointer instead. However, I get the wrong results when I try to print my list after deleting the middle node.

I saw this question
[deleting a node in the middle of a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531201/deleting-a-node-in-the-middle-of-a-linked-list) and I don't know how is my delete node function different from the answer.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef struct Node node;
void addfirstnode( u8 );
void addnode( u8 );
void print( void );
void deletenode( u8 key );
void deleteonlynode();
void deletefirstnode();

struct Node
{
    u8 x;
    node *next;
};
node *head;
u8 length = 0;


void main( void )
{
    u8 x;
    printf( "\nTo add node enter 0\nTo print linked list enter 1\nTo exit press 2\nTo delete node press 3\nYour Choice:" );
    scanf( "%d", &x );
    if ( x == 2 )
    {
        printf( "\nThank You\nGood Bye" );
    }
    while ( x != 2 )
    {
        switch ( x )
        {
            u8 n;
            u8 key;
            case 0:            //Add node
                printf( "\nPlease enter first value:" );
                scanf( "%d", &n );
                if ( length == 0 )
                {
                    addfirstnode( n );
                    //printf("%d",head->x);
                }
                else
                {
                    addnode( n );
                }
                printf( "\nNode added , Thank you\n" );
                break;

            case 1:            //Print
                print();
                break;

            case 3:            //DeleteNode
                printf( "\nPlease enter value to be deleted:" );
                scanf( "%d", &key );
                deletenode( key );
                //deletefirstnode();
                break;

            default:
                printf( "\nInvalid Choice please try again\n" );
        }
        printf( "\nTo add node enter 0\nTo print linked list enter 1\nTo exit press 2\nTo delete node press 3\nYour Choice:" );
        scanf( "%d", &x );
        if ( x == 2 )
        {
            printf( "\nThank You\nGood Bye" );
        }
    }
    //where do I use free();
}

void addfirstnode( u8 n )
{
    head = ( node * ) malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    head->next = NULL;
    head->x = n;
    length++;
}

void addnode( u8 n )
{
    node *last = head;
    while ( ( last->next ) != NULL )
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = ( node * ) malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    ( last->next )->next = NULL;
    ( last->next )->x = n;
    length++;
}

void print( void )
{
    node *last = head;
    u8 count = 1;
    printf( "\n---------------------" );
    if ( last == NULL )
    {
        printf( "\nList is empty" );
    }
    while ( last != NULL )
    {
        printf( "\nNode Number %d = %d", count, last->x );
        last = last->next;
        count++;
    }
    printf( "\n---------------------" );
    printf( "\n" );
}

void deletenode( u8 key )
{
    node *last = head;
    //node*postlast = NULL;
    if ( ( last->x == key ) && ( last->next == NULL ) )
    {
        deleteonlynode();
    }
    else
    {
        while ( last != NULL )
        {
            if ( ( last->x ) == key )
            {
                printf( "value to be deleted is found" );
                node *temp = last->next;
                last->next = last->next->next;
                free( temp );
                length--;
            }
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
}

void deleteonlynode()
{
    printf( "\n Deleting the only node" );
    free( head );
    head = NULL;
    length--;
}

void deletefirstnode()
{
    printf( "\n Deleting the first node" );
    node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free( temp );
    length--;
}
```

Comment: Why do almost all beginners cast malloc? Where do you learn it?

Comment: @Broman I initially thought that was the only way to do it but your question made me look things up and I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094394/why-do-we-cast-return-value-of-malloc)

Comment: But I'm curious. Where did you get that idea? It's not like it's something that you do without someone telling you.

Comment: @Broman I probably saw it in a code example on tutorialspoint and guessed that was the only way to do it.

Comment: That explains it. Don't trust that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is removing the wrong item from the linked list:

See:

```
        if ( ( last->x ) == key )
        {
            printf( "value to be deleted is found" );
            node *temp = last->next;     // last->next? No, just last.
            last->next = last->next->next;
            free( temp );
            length--;
        }
```

`last` is pointing at the element to be removed.  But then the code assigns `temp` to point at `last->next` (NOT `last`), and then cuts that from the list.

So by looking at `node->next` rather than the current node, it's possible to trim it out since you're starting from the pointer before the one to remove.  Basically your code was almost there already.

```
void deletenode( u8 key )
{
    node *ptr = head;

    if ( ( ptr->x == key ) )
    {
        // Delete the first/head element
        node *temp = ptr;
        head = head->next;
        free( temp );
        length--;
    }
    else
    {
        while ( ptr->next != NULL )
        {
            if ( ( ptr->next->x ) == key )
            {
                printf( "value to be deleted is found" );
                node *temp = ptr->next;
                ptr->next = ptr->next->next;
                free( temp );
                length--;
            }
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I took the liberty of renaming `last` to `ptr` because it was confusing me.

EDIT: Updated to remove the head cleanly too.

Comment: Great Thanks a lot I get it now

Comment: I updated the function to be able to delete the first node as well if the key was found there :
`if ((last->x == key)) 
 {
  deletefirstnode();
 }` However when I use this condition `//if ((last->x == key) && (last == head))` the function doesn't work properly and here is the implementation: `void deletefirstnode()
 {
  printf("\n Deleting the first node");
  node* temp = head; 
  head = head->next;
  free(temp);
  length--;
 }`

Comment: If you need to remove the head node, just keep a pointer to it, then `head = head->next;`.  Don't try to make it complicated ;)  `head->next` is either `NULL` or just another node-pointer.

Comment: BTW: did you notice the bug in your remove function?  It's actually removing all non-head nodes that match.  A `break` would fix it.

Comment: yes you are right I didn't notice that bug. I will add a break thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be deleting  `last->next` while `last` should be the node that matches the key.
I guess the following code may be shorter and do the deletion

```
node* head;

/* returns the node* the previous_node->next should be after the deletion */
node* delete_node(node* current, u8 key) {
    if (current == NULL) return NULL;  // deletion comes to end
    if (head->x == key) {
        node* temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        return delete_node(temp, key);
    }
    current->next = delete_node(current->next, key);
    return current;
}


int main() {
    // build the linked list
    // ...
    head = delete_node(head, key);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this implement (which uses recursion instead of loop) may cause StackOverFlow if the list is too long. I had not tested if gcc would optimize the recursion out.

Comment: I am still dealing with short lists so I don't think that will be a problem. Thanks a lot